# Support for pushing complete data to webhook in IOT central Rules

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I want to get complete data when condition is met,

For example,

In below data, if type is equal to "Unknown", i want to push whole json data to webhook service in rules,

```
{ 
"timestamp": " 2017-04-28T08:16:14Z", 
"type": "Unknown", 
"mac": "ABC1010000AD", 
"bleName": "ABC", 
"rssi": -76, 
"rawData": "3A4E24FB1AFCFC6EB07647825FDA50693A4E2" 
}
```

Comment: Hi Raj, is the "whole json data" you are describing above the entire message the device is sending to IoT Central? Or are you asking for some properties and metadata not currently being emitted by the device to be included in the webhook payload?

Comment: @VivianLiu-MSFT device is sending above entire message to IOT central.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Azure IoT Central supports only Rules for Device Telemetry Data and Properties. 
Your device message contains only one telemetry data such as *rssi*, the other properties are non-telemetry data. It will be nice to have a rule condition also on the non-telemetry data, however in this current version of the Azure IoT Central is only way to obtain a full device message is using a **Continuous Data Export**.

Note, there is no filtering for data exporting, just only turn on/off delivery, so this logic must be done on the consumer side, for instance in the ServiceBusTrigger function. The other option is exporting data to the streaming pipe (Event Hub) and using a standard streaming technique to analyze events.